# Nine Positive Distinct Integers Placed Around a Circle

Tags: geometry

Nine distinct positive integers are arranged in a circle such that the product of any two non-adjacent numbers in the circle is a multiple of n and the product of any two adjacent numbers in the circle is not a multiple of n, where n is a fixed positive integer. Find the
smallest possible value for n.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?  E.g. $n$ is not $1$ or a prime.